# Calling Axios in React results in Network Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to run the following command in a React component after clicking a button:

```
import axios from 'axios'    
export function callApi(index, callback) {

axios.get('http://localhost:8080/search?index=120&json=true&all=true')
    .then(res => {
        alert(res)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        alert("error: " + error)
    })
```

}

It works fine when I'm running the code in node,

```
var axios = require('axios')
axios.get('http://localhost:8080/search?index=120&json=true&all=true')
    .then(res => {
        alert(res)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        alert("error: " + error)
    })
```

But when I call it after clicking a button, I get an alert that says "Error: Network Error." I've tried running it with fetch() instead with no CORS either, but I'm getting an empty response instead of one with data.

```
fetch('http://192.168.1.156:8080/search?index=120&json=true&all=true', {mode: 'no-cors'})
    .then(res => {
        alert(res)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        alert("error: " + error)
    })
```

I've tried running this with other APIs like `api.github.com` but I get the same result. It works in node, but not React.

Comment: can you log the error in console and get more info about it ?

Comment: Are you sure the pc is connected to internet ? try to call the same link from browser.. is it working ?

Comment: Are you sure your requests using axios/fetch are not cross origin requests? Also, definitely try and log the response to the console, and be sure to check the network request/response from your browser's dev tools, if it's a browser originated request.

Comment: I fixed it - it was because I was using a cross origin request and the server API (which I wrote) was not equipped to handle it. I've included a code snippet of the fixed code for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several grueling hours, I finally found what was wrong with my server. It was not able to handle CORS. The code looked like this before:

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  ...
})
```

Turns out I just had to enable cors. It works after running `npm install cors` and changing the server code to:

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
var cors = require('cors')

app.use(cors())
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  ...
})
```